# Older version of a git repository as a submodule

Tags: git, github

How can I add an older version of a repository as a submodule to my github repo?

I'd like to use abraham/twitteroauth's older 0.5.0 version, which is compatible with php 5.3.

This just add the last version:

```
git submodule add <path>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

which is not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: git add + init + update just add the last version of the repository

Comment: Isn't this similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)? Shouldn't matter, if you need a specific branch or commit.

Comment: @StephenKing can't figure out how those answers can be adapted to my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the submodule, checkout 0.5.0, and commit.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.git twitteroauth
cd twitteroauth
git checkout 0.5.0
git commit -a
```

The commit will show a change to twitteroauth recording the 0.5.0 commit it's now at.

```
diff --git a/twitteroauth b/twitteroauth
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..875918b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/twitteroauth
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Subproject commit 875918bad4f1e9651635ee3107f5edcce34b4acd
```